# Как рефакторить метод со многими вложенными конструкциями в C# или Java

Tags: java, c#, шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг

Слышал, что не очень хорошо, когда в методе много вложенных конструкций. Видимо, так говорят потому, что код становится не читабельным.

Например,

```
public void Do(int a, bool b, List<X> c, object d = null)
{
    if ()
    {
        foreach ()
        {
            if ()
            {

            }
            else if ()
            {
                if ()
                {
                    foreach ()
                    {
                        if ()
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Какие существуют подходы, как такие методы рефакторить в уже написанном коде? Особенно, в случаях, когда у метода много входных параметров и все они как-то переплетены внутри него, так что и не догадаешься, как разбить на разные методы. Причем, когда код заново не получится написать, потому, что всего там не понимаешь, риск, что перестанет правильно работать. Существуют ли какие-нибудь шаблонные подходы?

Приходит в голову:

- использовать ключевые слова типа `return`, `continue`, `break`

Например, вместо

```
if (x != null)
{
    //code
}
```

писать так:

```
if (x == null)
    return;
//code
```

Еще чего-нибудь посоветуете?

Comment: Разбить логику на соответствующие классы

Comment: Разнести по методам...

Comment: Это еще что! Бывает гораздо хуже, когда в вызов метода среди параметров, пихают вызов конструктора класса, а у него еще несколько параметров один из которых, тоже вызывает конструктор или другой метод, вот этот матрёшечный ад покруче будет.

Answer (score 7):

Почитайте книгу Роберта Мартина "Чистый код" (Clean Code).

Не все мысли автора бесспорны, но почитать точно стоит. По крайней мере после чтения, многие вещи будут восприниматься немного по другому.

[Ссылка на книгу в ozon.ru](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5011068/)

P.S. Электронная версия легко гуглится.

Comment: Повезло, эта книжка оказалась в нашей комнате (в офисе).

Answer (score 2):

Можно выполнить декомпозицию, что бы в каждом отдельном методе выполнялся 1 цикл, который вызывает другой метод.

В этом случае получается самодокументированный код.

Если в `if` находится какое-то большое выражение, то можно сделать отдельную функцию, которая возвращает true/false и опять же получается саомдокументированный код.

В некоторых случаях `if` можно поменять на `switch`

В "Чистый код", как раз такие советы и даются.

---

Еще можно `foreach` и `if` заменить на LINQ выражение и несколько строчек сократить до 1. В некоторых случаях(когда условие небольшое) это не скажется на читаемости, а в итоге несколько строчек сократятся до 1-2.

Comment: несколько if на один switch, а просто замена if на switch как-то не логично смотрится в тексте